# Issue in Lineage OS 20 : OmxStore: omx common prefix: no nodes

Tags: lineageos, android-13, graphics

I am not able to screen record in lineage 20 and i am getting error with OpenMax component. Omx (OpenMAX) Component Node not initiating that's why not getting "OMX" as an omx common prefix and also not creating Component instance for video encoding.

Please check attach logs below.

```
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: called createOMXPlugin for Goldfish
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: useOmxCodecs 54 found prop debug.stagefright.ccodec val 0
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: useAndroidGoldfishComponentInstance 85 found prop ro.boot.qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec val 2
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: found and use kComponents[i].name OMX.android.goldfish.vp8.decoder
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: useAndroidGoldfishComponentInstance 85 found prop ro.boot.qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec val 2
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: found and use kComponents[i].name OMX.android.goldfish.vp9.decoder
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: useAndroidGoldfishComponentInstance 85 found prop ro.boot.qemu.hwcodec.avcdec val 2
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: found and use kComponents[i].name OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: enumerate OMX.android.goldfish.vp8.decoder component
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: enumerate OMX.android.goldfish.vp9.decoder component
D GoldfishOMXPlugin: enumerate OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder component
I SoftOMXPlugin: createOMXPlugin
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml...
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.data.IRadioData/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.messaging.IRadioMessaging/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.modem.IRadioModem/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.network.IRadioNetwork/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.sim.IRadioSim/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.voice.IRadioVoice/slot1 in device VINTF manifest.
I servicemanager: Found android.hardware.radio.config.IRadioConfig/default in device VINTF manifest.
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 85 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 88 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 91 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 95 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 98 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 101 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 104 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_audio.xml...
I bt_vhci_forwarder: ignore 0xff packet
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_telephony.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_video.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_performance.xml...
I MediaCodecsXmlParser: Did not find media_codecs_shaping.xml in search path
I HidlServiceManagement: Registered android.hardware.media.omx@1.0::IOmx/default
I HidlServiceManagement: Removing namespace from process name android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service to omx@1.0-service.
I android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service: IOmx HAL service created.
I OmxStore: omx common prefix: no nodes
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 85 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 88 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 91 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 95 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 98 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 101 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: Ignoring unrecognized tag <MediaCodec> at line 104 of /vendor/etc/media_codecs.xml
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_audio.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_telephony.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_google_video.xml...
D MediaCodecsXmlParser: parsing /vendor/etc/media_codecs_performance.xml...
I MediaCodecsXmlParser: Did not find media_codecs_shaping.xml in search path
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.aac.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.amrnb.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.amrwb.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.flac.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.g711.alaw.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.g711.mlaw.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.gsm.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.mp3.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.opus.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.raw.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.vorbis.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.aac.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.amrnb.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.amrwb.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.flac.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.h264.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.h263.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.hevc.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.mpeg4.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.android.goldfish.vp8.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.vp8.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.android.goldfish.vp9.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.vp9.decoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.h264.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.h263.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.mpeg4.encoder] not found in IOmx
I OmxStore: node [OMX.google.vp8.encoder] not found in IOmx
```

Anyone have any solution for this, Please provide.

I am debugging and checking but not found proper solution.

Comment: Also posted on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77513893/2821954

Comment: Could you [edit] and mention how you are trying to record the screen and the device model? Have you searched if this is perhaps a known issue of this OS build?